# How do you profile a Go fasthttp/router application?

Tags: go

I'd like to profile my Go HTTP server application to see if there are places where it can be optimized. I'm using the `fasthttp` package with the `fasthttp/router` package, and I'm struggling to figure out how to hook up `pprof`.

The basic setup looks like this, obviously very abridged:

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    r := router.New()
    r.GET("/", index)
    r.GET("/myroute", myrouteFn)

    h := r.Handler

    if err := limitedListenAndServe(*addr, fasthttplogger.Tiny(h)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error in ListenAndServe: %s", err)
    }
}
```

First, I tried following a fairly straightforward guide like [this one](https://flaviocopes.com/golang-profiling/), and added this line in my `main()` function (per the guide) in addition to the corresponding import. That changed the above to this:

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    r := router.New()
    r.GET("/", index)
    r.GET("/myroute", myrouteFn)

    h := r.Handler

    if err := limitedListenAndServe(*addr, fasthttplogger.Tiny(h)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error in ListenAndServe: %s", err)
    }

    defer profile.Start().Stop()
}
```

After doing that, I ran my program, made a bunch of requests that I was interested in profiling, and then terminated the server. That created a `cpu.pprof` file, but the file was empty (zero bytes) when I went to run it through the `go tool pprof` command to generate the graph.

After a bit more sleuthing I found [this Gist](https://github.com/dgryski/trifles/blob/master/fastpprof/main.go) that I suspect would work if I were using totally vanilla `fasthttp`.

Trying to combine that with my application, I'm still stuck. Conceptually, I think the solution is to use the `fasthttpadaptor` to convert the `net/http/pprof` to a `fasthttp` route. But the Gist that I was looking at is using its own router to do the mux, I'd and rather not rewrite all the routes using a different router in my server.

How would I go about making the profiling data available here?

Comment: What do you mean "the program never really terminating as such"? It's still a process that starts and eventually exits, web servers aren't special. If you add that line, run your server, push some requests through it, and then shut down the server, you should have a profile with some data in it.

Comment: That was my thought as well, but I wasn't totally sure how the profiler works. Very new to Go! That said, the `cpu.pprof` file is definitely empty after I stop the server. What would I look for to see why that's empty?

Comment: Hard to say, because the code in your question doesn't invoke pprof at all. Can you edit the question to show the code you're using that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Sure, I've made that a bit clearer. I cannot stress enough how much of a neophyte I am here. Many apologies if my questions are extremely basic!

Comment: You're starting profiling immediately before the application exits, so I'd expect an empty profile. You need to put that line at the *top* of `main`.

Comment: A `defer` on the last line of a function is pointless, so if you ever see that it's a clue that something isn't right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`net/http/pprof`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go) for profiling.
fasthttp provides custom [implementation](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/blob/master/pprofhandler/pprof.go) for the same. You can use that same as the `net/http/pprof`.

To use this, register the handler as:

```
import "github.com/valyala/fasthttp/pprofhandler"

...

r.GET("/debug/pprof/{profile:*}", pprofhandler.PprofHandler)
```

Then you can use this to profile.

```
go tool pprof http://host:port/debug/pprof/profile
```

Or you can also visit http://host:port/debug/pprof/ to see more types of profiles available.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel a bit silly I didn't see that going through the different packages.